# Unexpected token } JavaScript SharePoint2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, javascript, development

I am apending an `<ul>` tag with jQuery, I have added an `<li>` and inside it I added an`<>`. And I want when user click on that link open it in a Dialog;

I have the following code and I am getting this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`:`(function(event){MenuDialog(
})`

```
$(finalname).append("<li><a id='hlTopAdd' onclick='MenuDialog('"+URL+"')' >Click Here</a></li>");



  function MenuDialog(URL) {

    var options = {
    url: URL,
    title: 'test',
    allowMaximize: true,
    showClose: true,
    width: 630,
    height: 589

};   
SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
}
```

How ever if I call MenuDialog() without any parameter, and inside function if I initialize `url:` to and static link it works fine example `url: http://mysite/mypage.aspx`

Hope you understood me!

Thanks

Comment: What IDE are you using? Are you using JSLint to check your code before execution?

Comment: I am using sharepoint designer

Comment: are you tried to add your URL at onclick='MenuDialog('"+URL+"')' ? is it working in this case ?

Comment: That doesn't do much to help. https://code.visualstudio.com/ is free

Comment: @M.Qassas yes I tried but it is not working, still getting same error

Comment: Don't you think your last `}` is redundant?

Comment: @Kai I tried to remove it and everything went wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue in passing variable to `MenuDialog` function , so try

```
  onClick='MenuDialog(\""+URL+"\")'
```

Or to avoid passing variable issue, remove `on click` in your `<a> tag` , Then add the `on click` as the following

```
$("#hlTopAdd").on('click', function() {
  MenuDialog(URL);
});
```

Comment: It is working perfect my brother